# how to remove those ugly seams between patch boundaries from the texture atlas?

Tags: opengl, textures, seam

When I try to render a textured 3D model with a GLSL shader with OpenTK, I get very ugly seams between texture patches. Does anyone know how to remove them?

[image: This picture is my rendering result]

[image: This picture is the texture atlas]

the 3D model comes from the [sketchfab.com](https://sketchfab.com/models/5f83563bfb5542bf9ee301d565ae36a1),

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and specially the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing your code no one can help much, but just make some guess.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to tell from this screenshot whether the issue is mipmapping or a lack of mesh segmentation, so I'll respond to both.

**Possibility 1: Mipmapping**

Ensure that mipmapping is turned off on the atlas. In GL that means your minification filter should be linear or nearest, but *not* the mipmapped variants.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texAtlas);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

That atlas is packed incredibly tightly and standard mip generation is going to blur across the patch boundaries, resulting in seams.

**Possibility 2: Lack of Mesh Segmentation**

It could also be that the model is being loaded (incorrectly) as one contiguous mesh, whereas the texture atlas makes it clear that the mesh should be broken up into many pieces.

The ugly seams are a result of the fact that OpenGL is interpolating texture coordinates (UVs) across boundaries where the mesh is intended to be discontinuous. Each of the little 'pieces' in the texture atlas should correspond to one distinct patch on the mesh, and the vertices that correspond to the edges of that patch must not be shared with others, because the texture coordinates are discontinuous.

Some mesh formats, like the common .obj, can specify vertices in bizarre ways that must be handled carefully in order to work correctly in, e.g., OpenGL. For example, a vertex can be associated with two distinct texture coordinates. To render the model correctly, we must duplicate such a vertex, creating one unique vertex for each set of texture coordinates. Check the documentation for whatever API you're using to load the model, and see if it mentions vertex duplication, texture coordinates, etc.

Comment: Dear Josh Parnell, thank you very much！Your answer is very helpful. 
Based on your analysis, I think the problem comes from the Possibility 2. So I will work on it. 
Obviously, it is not easy to solve it. I need time to try.....